# Add fixed bottom menu on Xamarin Forms with Prism MasterDetail

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms with Prism and I need to create a layout with a sidebar menu and a fixed bar at the bottom of the screen with quick actions like instagram app for iOS and Android.

I was thinking in use MasterDetail but how can I add that fixed bar at bottom of the Detail controller and keep it when detail page changes?

And the second thing is that I have a specific page that has form sections separated by tabs, so how can I render tabs at the top of the page for iOS (like Android)?

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi! I created a control extending a Grid to distribute my icons (images) with events to call the expected action, and then I called it inside my pages. In the pages, I used a Grid layout to fix that control at the footer. It might exists a better solution but it worked for me.

Comment: @CleytonT. I am interest in doing something similar. Does this bottom footer stay static when navigating? It doesn't redraw (noticeable) at every navigation?

Comment: Hi @MagnusJohansson, I ended up creating a custom control for the bottom menu based on Grid layout to organize the icons and labels. And in the pages where that menu needs to be displayed, I used a Grid layout with 2 rows using star size for the first row and fixed size for the second row where the menu is instantiated. It's not the best solution but it worked. It is re-rendered every time you navigate =(. Check the TabbedPage in the recent version of XF that contains an option to place the menu at the bottom on Android but I'm not sure if you can two menus (top and bottom) on the same page.